# My PC displays a black screen on boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, graphics-card, hardware-failure, troubleshooting

I was just in the middle of gaming when both my screens went grey and then all sound stopped. I left it a few minutes before shutting my PC down by holding the power button, then left it again for a little while before starting it up.

The HP logo appears but has some vertical tearing with lighter blue lines, the spinning wheel still does it's thing, but then the screen just goes black.

I ran the HP system diagnostics on the video memory as I suspected that might be the issue, and the test instantly failed.

I have been considering getting a new graphics card for a little while. If I was to install a new one, will my PC boot properly again?

If not, is there anything else I can try (I.e. check drivers etc)? I'd rather not have to do a system restore or anything like that as I don't want to risk losing a bunch of work!

My PC is an HP ENVY 700-311na; 
Motherboard: MS-7826 (Kaili)
CPU: Intel Core i7 4790
RAM: 16GB
Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 270 & Intel HD Graphics 4600 (GT2) integrated

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Cross post: https://serverfault.com/questions/919074/my-video-memory-failed-and-i-just-get-a-black-screen-on-boot

Comment: Delete the ServerFault post to start.... Consider going into UEFI/BIOS and disable the AMD and force it to use the Intel GPU and see if that allows you to see video past the point where it stays a black screen. Do so if possible with the Intel and then do so with the AMD and see what results you get with one or the other being completely disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PimpJuiceIT. I didn't realise cross-posting was against the rules, I figured I might just have more of a chance of getting replies that way. How do I go about disabling the GPUs from BIOS?

Comment: I see an option to enable/disable integrated graphics, but I tried toggling this earlier and had no luck with that one.

Comment: Turn on the computer and repeatedly press the `F10` key for eight seconds until  you to a screen to see more options and such.

Comment: Open the enclosure and be sure to get all the dust out and that all fans are spinning and blowing air where there is one when you power it on including on any GPU cards, mounted to the enclosure, etc. Look at the motherboard circuitry and such and be sure nothing looks charred, swollen or oozing capacitors on the motherboard, etc. Rule out obvious overheat type damage and clear out all dust and turn it on and confirm all fans spin. If you can unseat and reseat the GPU, RAM, etc. that probably wouldn't hurt to confirm everything is firmly seated.

Comment: What did you figure out with this? Did any of my comment advice help or you still have trouble?